# How to get the total count of rows in a repeater?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I am using a Repeater control to display data, The data source contains multiple records
 which are displayed in the repeater, what i need is to get the difference of two list items and assign it to another list item, I have used the below mentioned code works fine for the first record but doesn't display all the records

aspx.cs Code

```
DataSet dsJobCardHistory =new DataSet(); 
double dcPriceIncl;
double dcPriceExcl;
double dcTax;
protected void Job_History()
{

    dsJobCardHistory = objReportManager.Get_JobCard_History(strCustNo, strTranId);

     dcPriceIncl = Convert.ToDouble(dsJobCardHistory.Tables[0].Rows[0][6].ToString());
      dcTax = dcPriceIncl * 0.14;
      dcPriceExcl = dcPriceIncl - dcTax;
}
protected void repJobCard_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{     
       if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
            {
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblRepPrice")).Text = 
                    Convert.ToString(dcPriceExcl);
             ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblRepTax")).Text =
                    Convert.ToString(dcTax);
                ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblRepTotal")).Text=
                    Convert.ToString(dcPriceIncl);
            }
    }
}
```

aspx code

```
 <font style="font-size:14px"><strong><asp:Label ID="lblRepPrice" runat="server"
 Text=""></asp:Label></strong></font>
 </td>
 <td align="center" width="15%">
 <font style="font-size:14px"><strong><asp:Label ID="lblRepTax" runat="server" 
 Text=""></asp:Label></strong></font>
 </td>
 <td align="center" width="15%">
  <font style="font-size:14px"><strong><asp:Label ID="lblRepTotal" runat="server"
  Text=""></asp:Label></strong></font>
  </td>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: I need to subtract the value of two items lblRepTotal and lblRepPrice of this Repeater and assign the value to the next item lblRepTax, the code works just for the first row, I somehow need to get the count of rows so that i could iterate it respectively.

Comment: Where is your code where you done that calculation part

Comment: The sample code you posted won't be helpful be more precise

Comment: dcPriceIncl = Convert.ToDouble(dsJobCardHistory.Tables[0].Rows[0][6].ToString());
          dcTax = dcPriceIncl * 0.14;
          dcPriceExcl = dcPriceIncl - dcTax;

Comment: @Shahid is that calculated each time within the `ItemDataBound` event method?  Please edit your question to include the calculation code.

Comment: @mdmullinax I have made the edits.

Comment: @shaid what u mean by it work for first record....

Comment: it displays the correct records only for the first row the second row is left blank

Comment: look at my answer replace ur line with that i m sure it works.....i make edit in ur if......how many rows u have..

Comment: No it doesn't, i already tried that, I get the same content in the second row as well.As far as the number of rows are concerned I dont know it depends upon the customer selected there can be just one row or multiple rows

Comment: hmmm its not left blank right...mean u r geting record for row.....no its ur own logic how manipulate them....

Comment: and u will always get same record for all rowsbcz ur job history is called one time and it always calculating for first row...dsJobCardHistory.Tables[0].Rows[0][6];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27923/discussion-between-shahid-and-amit-singh)

Comment: i m in office and chat is blocked./////....calll ur job history function in itemboud inside if it will solve ur problem

Comment: I have sent you the code in chat, if you can spare some time for it please let me know any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I did that but the all label gets overwritten by the last record I use code like this                                                 for (int i = 0; i < dsJobCardHistory.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++)
 
        {
            dcPriceIncl = Convert.ToDouble(dsJobCardHistory.Tables[0].Rows[i][6].ToString());                                                     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                {
                    ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblRepPrice")).Text = Convert.ToString(dcPriceExcl);

Answer (score 2):

As u said its working for first time only so Replace Your this line

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
```

with....

```
 if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Give the `[xp:repeat]`  an ID value e.g. `idvaluestring`
2. in SSJS uses `getComponent("idvalueString").getRowCount()`

The Class of the RepeatControl is:

`com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspDataIterator`

```
<xp:repeat var="voyageChoicesCollection"
indexVar="voyageChoicesCollectionIndex" 
value="#{ProfileListRepeat}"
id="voyageChoicesCollectionID"> 

var vccID:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspDataIterator = getComponent("voyageChoicesCollectionID");
vccID.getRowCount()
```